# How to test a poller based db operation service from SOAPUi

Tags: testing, automation, soapui, poller

Looking for suggestions

We have a requirement to automate the test scenario where we had to get the details from Poller based service(this will fetch the data when ever a data updated on existing or created a new record), once the record is picked we internally process them.

I would like to know how we can automate the process to pick the record as part of the testing.

Comment: Is the data exposed in a web service ? Because you added a tag SoapUI.

Comment: @ou_ryperd No, here the data should be consumed by the webservice when ever an update or insert made into some table. Lets take an example of EMP table. if any new Employee joined in the organisation a new entry will be made to this table which will triger emppoller service to process the emp details to subsequent system. what we are looking here is a suggestions to capture this scenario via automation.